# How to get audit history data using web api in 2016 on premise CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I need to get the audit history details for specific record wise using web api only not though custom code.

I tried to get the audit history by using the below code. But it is not returning the required information as I need the old and value column wise. 
https://xxxxx/api/data/v8.2/audits?`$filter=_objectid_value%20eq%20AFF6BF88-8A78-CDAE-8829-5B702E2F89D9`

Then I tried the `"RetrieveRecordChangeHistory"` function. It is working in the custom c# code but not working in the web api.

> https://xxxx/api/data/v8.2/RetrieveRecordChangeHistory(Target=@Target)?@Target={%22contactid%22:%22AFF6BF88-8A78-CDAE-8829-5B702E2F89D9%22,%22@odata.type%22:%22Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact%22}.

The above url giving the below error.

> {   "error":{
>       "code":"","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'RetrieveRecordChangeHistory'.","innererror":{
>         "message":"Resource not found for the segment 'RetrieveRecordChangeHistory'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException","stacktrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.CreateFirstSegment(String
>   segmentText)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.ParsePath(ICollection`1
>   segments)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathFactory.BindPath(ICollection`1
>   segments, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUriParser.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel
>   model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath, ODataUriResolverSetttings
>   resolverSettings, Boolean enableUriTemplateParsing)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel
>   model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel
>   model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath)"
>       }   } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RetrieveRecordChangeHistory` function was not available from web api in CRM 2016 (v8.2) and it was added in web api function list later, which is v9

[v8.2 functions list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt607866%28v%3Dcrm.8%29)

[v9 functions list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/functions?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sorry for late reply.